# Polynomial in Circular Linked List

Tags: c

While printing the polynomial the first coefficient and exponent are getting printed repeatedly for n( no of terms ) times.

```
Input:
     No of terms: 3
     Enter coefficient and exponent: 3 3
     Enter coefficient and exponent: 2 2
     Enter coefficient and exponent: 1 1

Output:
3x^(3) + 3x^(3) + 3x^(3)
```

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int coef , exp;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* create( struct Node* );

int main(){

    int val , choice , loc;
    struct Node* A = NULL;
    struct Node* B = NULL;

    A = create( A );
    B = create( B );
    display( A );
    display( B );

    do{
        printf("\n\n-----POLYNOMIAL OPERATIONS-----\n1.Addition\n2.Multiply\n3.Evaluate\n4.Exit\n--->");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch( choice ){
            case 1://Adding
                    break;
            case 2://Multiplying
                    break;
            case 3://Evaluating
                    break;
        }

    }while( choice != 4 );


    return 0;
}

struct Node* create( struct Node* p ){

    int i , c , x , t;
    printf("\nNumber of terms: ");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for( i = 0 ; i < t ; i++ ){
        struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        printf("Enter Coefficient & Exponent: ");
        scanf("%d%d",&c,&x);
        temp->coef = c;
        temp->exp = x;
        if( p == NULL ){
            p = temp;
            temp->next = p;
        }else{
            struct Node* temp1 = p;
            while( temp1->next != p ) temp1 = temp1->next;
            temp1->next = temp;
            temp->next = p;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

void display( struct Node* p ){

    struct Node* temp = p;
    printf("\nPOLYNOMIAL: ");

    do{
        printf("%dx^(%d)",p->coef,p->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
        if( temp != p ){
            printf(" + ");
        }
    }while( temp != p );
}
```

Comment: In the function `create` you link the `.next` field of `temp` to `temp` (because you do `p = temp; temp->next = p;`).

Comment: Why do you use a circular list?  Why not a regular (non-circular) list?  There isn't an obvious benefit that I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change:

```
 do{
        printf("%dx^(%d)",temp->coef,temp->exp);
        temp = temp->next;
        ...
```

Right now you are dereferencing the initial node every time you go through the display loop!

I want to point out that, as the `display()` function is written right now, you will have a segfault if a NULL pointer is ever passed to it. Exactly that happens if you enter `0` at either of the prompts for `Number of terms:`.